# How to create a phpUnit test for images?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a simple fileupload (image upload) which resizes this image to a smaller one. To create a phpUnit test for this resize function I need a mock object which represents an image.

Is the best practice to use a 'testimage' or is there a better way??

Comment: Have you `class ImageResizeHelper` or something like that? phpUnit is to work with classes more, but still you can just call your function, put your dummy image into it and then just assert what the size you expect. PHP has this to get sizes of images: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: @jaro1989 No, i use the $_FILE variable which contain the data by the upload

Comment: This question might not be a good fit for Stack Overflow because what "best practice" is may result in subjective and opinionated answers rather than factual answers as are preferred by the Stack Overflow community

Comment: Could you provide your method's code, so I could try to write a good answer for you.

Comment: @jaro1989 I load the file-data by the constructor into the object  `public function __construct($fileData, $uploadFolderName)
    {
        $this->files = $fileData;
        $this->uploadFolder = $uploadFolderName;
    }` and this is the problem. [Git link to this Project](https://github.com/michael-mammut/imageresizer/blob/master/control/FileHandler.php)

Comment: I see, you aren't using autoloader, hope, you will add it soon. And you have exact method for your resizing called 'resizeImage' so this test must be about this 'unit' of your class. Will write a little example for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
namespace tests\control;

use SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\TestCase;

class FileHandlerTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $files = [];

    /**
     * Put your temp image into your filesystem.
     * (Not good as unit tests must work with any system,
     * but my research about mocking resources gave me nothing)
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/testImage.jpg')) {
            try {
                rmdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/testImage.jpg');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Exception('You have no permission to delete files in this directory:' . $e);
            }

        } else {
            $image = imagecreate(500, 500);
            try {
                imagejpeg($image, dirname(__FILE__) . '/testImage.jpg');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Exception('You have no permission to create files in this directory:' . $e);
            }
        }

        $this->files[] = '/testImage.jpg';
    }

    public function testOperation()
    {
        $example = new \FileHandler($this->files,  dirname(__FILE__));
        /**
         * Set here all the variable inside your file,
         * your code isn't working at this moment.
         * Properties to set: uploadFolder, files
         */
        $example->process();

        /**
         * Get you new image from test dir here.
         * It's yours TODO :p
         */

        /** @var resource $newPicture */
        $size = getimagesize($newPicture);

        /**
         * also count it yourself, as I can't reproduce your code
         */
        $this->assertEquals('200', $size[0]);
        $this->assertEquals('200', $size[1]);

    }

    /**
     * Deleting of test images. No try/catch here as it would fire on setup
     */
    protected function tearDown()
    {
        if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/testImage.jpeg')) {
            rmdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/testImage.jpeg');
        }

        if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/newImage.jpeg')) {
            rmdir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/newImage.jpeg');
        }
    }
}
```

You still have to make some work about it. And I'd prefer not to test such things. SetUp-method's comment is about it.